# Selecting layers in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

*Python 3.7 and QGIS 3.6

I have a program that loads multiple layers, and now I need to select different layers to edit. Before I was managing fine with iface.activeLayer(), but now that I have multiple layers this is no longer an option.

My current code - additional layers are loaded later:

```
layer = iface.addVectorLayer(in_file, name, 'ogr')

iface.mapCanvas().refreshAllLayers()
layer = iface.mapCanvas().layer(0)

layer.startEditing()
```

This results in the following error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startEditing'

Interestingly, if I run the code when there is already a layer loaded, it works. This isn't an actual fix though, as it's not realistic for me to have a layer pre-loaded each time I run the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like:

```
in_file =  r'C:\Full\Path\To\Vector\File.gpkg'
name = 'Layer Name'
layer = QgsVectorLayer(in_file, name, 'ogr')
QgsProject().instance().addMapLayer(layer)
layer.startEditing()
```

I tested this in QGIS 3.4 on a new project and it worked fine with no other layers loaded (see image below).

[image]

It should also work fine when loading subsequent layers. However, if you want to be more explicit in referencing a layer, you could use something like the following (assuming that the `name` variable holds the reference to the name of the layer you want to put into edit mode):

```
in_file =  r'C:\Full\Path\To\Vector\File.gpkg'
name = 'Layer Name'
layer = QgsVectorLayer(in_file, name, 'ogr')
QgsProject().instance().addMapLayer(layer)
layer_to_edit = QgsProject().instance().mapLayersByName(name)[0]
layer_to_edit.startEditing()
```